# Difference between "Where are you living?" and "Where do you live?"

Tags: grammar

What is the difference in common usage between sentences like:

a) 
Where are you living? and Where do you live? or

b)
Are you traveling a lot? and Do you travel a lot?

Answer (score 8):

The difference is in the mind of the speaker. If the speaker conceptualises the question as referring to a temporary state (living in a particular place) or a repeated action over a limited period (travelling), then the continuous form is more likely.

So, if my friend moves to San Francisco on a two-year contract, I am more likely to ask her a couple of weeks later:  *Where are you living?* than *Where do you live?*

Similarly, if I want to know if a new acquaintance frequently travels on business or vacation, I ask: *Do you travel a lot?* But, I would be more likely to ask my San Francisco friend a few months after she's started her temporary contract: *Are you travelling a lot?*

---

It is worth quoting at length from Lewis in *The English Verb* (pages 85-87) for a better understanding of the reasons that native speakers choose one or other of the two forms exemplified in this question:

> We need to remember that this form (the present
>   continuous/progressive) is not technically a tense, but an aspect.
>   Aspects give the speaker's temporal interpretation of the event. They
>   do not refer to real time, but to psychological time - to the
>   speaker's perception of the temporal quality of the event.
>
> ...
>
> We need to contrast: *I live in Oxford* and  *I'm living in Oxford*.
>
> ...
>
> We need to remember that the speaker's choice of verb form conveys
>   both the fact, and his or her attitude to, or interpretation of, those
>   facts. The question is not whether my living in Oxford is a period of
>   time but whether, at the moment of speaking on a particular occasion,
>   I wish to emphasise that it is something which will occur for a
>   limited period of time.
>
> With *I'm living in Oxford*, the speaker conceptualises a temporary
>   state; in psychological time the period is limited. This limit is not
>   suggested by *I live in Oxford*.

Comment: Your understanding of the nuances of a native speaker's use of the English language and your ability to explain it is exemplary. (:

Comment: @Andrew. Thank you for the positive feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I find little difference. "Where are you living?" asks me what area, region or country I live in. "Where do you live? asks me the same, with the added hint or invitation to be more specific, even to the extent of giving my address.

I the second example I detect even less difference. Others may disagree.