# Different meaning according to present tense

Tags: present-tense

What's the difference in meaning between:

`I really enjoy working here` 
vs.
`I am really enjoying working here`?

Note: Example taken from `Advanced Language Practice with Key` by `Michael Vince with Peter Sunderland`, Present Time, exercise 5 c).

Comment: How are these two sentences presented or commented on by the writer of the grammar text? Are they part of a quiz question and if so, what does the answer key say?

Comment: @Shoe I don't want to imply the solution.
Actually it doesn't matter what's in the key. What I'm asking is simply - what is the difference in meaning between these two or if one of them is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks. I was interested to know how this issue is dealt with in the grammar book. You might find the answer to the following question useful since it gives a reason why the continuous form may be chosen over its simple equivalent: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287233/difference-between-where-are-you-living-and-where-do-you-live

Comment: The authors explain this, as well as anybody can here, in the section before the practice questions, right at the beginning, under the heading 'Explanations'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey thanks for information. I have already read this but still it justifies usage of present continous. There is no clarification there if present simple is possible and if yes - what's the difference in meaning. That was basically intention for my question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: So the book says, here are two possible phrases, and here is the difference in meaning between them. You then ask if both phrases are possible, and what the difference in meaning is. I am finding this very perplexing.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the explanation given by the author.

The present simple "I ... enjoy working here" is *always true*. I enjoyed working here when I started, I enjoy it now, I will enjoy it in the future. The company looks after its staff, the building is air-conditioned, the salary is good, the work is interesting.

The present continuous "I am ... enjoying working here" is *temporarily true*. We use it when we are talking about something confined to the present time, loosely defined. I am enjoying working here today, right now, this week, this month, because my boss is away, I have an interesting project, the cafeteria has improved, there is an attractive new colleague.

[image]